# Time complexity of nested loop dependent on the outer loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

This is a normal nested loop with `n^2` complexity

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n): # <-- dependent on n
        print(i,j)
```

I am having a hard time understanding why the next loop also has a `n^2` complexity even when it prints less statements

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(i): # <-- now it is dependent on i
       print(i,j)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's count the amount of times the innermost expression executes, so we put it this way:

- i = 0; j = **0**; innermost executes: **0 times**
- i = 1; j = 0, **1**; innermost executes: **1 time**
- i = 2; j = 0, 1, **2**; innermost executes: **2 times**
- i = 3; j = 0, 1, 2, **3**; innermost executes: **3 times**
- ...
- i = n; j = 0, 1, 2, ..., **n**; innermost executes: **n times**

(*For j-loop the termination condition is highlighted with bold. When j-loop reaches it, the innermost expression won't be executed and we start next (if any) iteration of the i-loop.*)

Thus, we'll have `1+2+3+...+n`. Which is `1/2(n*(n+1))`, which is `n^2`. Thus, the time complexity is still n^2.